# group numpy 3d array elements by value relevant to their index

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a 3 dimentional numpy array of an image screenshot. Before i display that image to the openCV window, i want to draw a rectangle around each group of pixels that have the same color and they are next to each other. There can be n groups of pixels with the same color but different index or position on the image. Which is the right way || direction to do this as fast as possible?

Image :=>

[image]
[image: cells represent pixels with color values]

```
cv2.namedWindow("Live", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Live", 480, 270)

# take screenshot
img = pyautogui.screenshot()
# screenshot into numpy array
imp_arr = np.array(img)

#### I want to process numpy array at this point.

frame = cv2.cvtColor(imp_arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imshow("Live", frame)
```

Comment: Can you share a sample image and the desired output?

Comment: added an image having rectangles on the pixels || fields of the ROI

Comment: I have read about numpy centroid but i do not really understand. I do not have a math || physics background.  Can I use numpy centroid to achieve that?

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand what's your task.

Comment: In the second image i have drawn a simple table with cells as pixels and in them some number value as color values. Lets say i have a numpy array with three dimensions: width, height, color_value.  How can get the coordinates i need to draw those rectangles in that table if those rectangles did not exist. Ignore the yellow rectangles. I want only the color values above 70.

Comment: In your example many of the outlines you have drawn are not rectangles. What is the exact output you want from this program?

Comment: you are correct, my drawing is the worst in relevance with that i mean. My goal is to have all the visible elements || components of a given web page in a list or dictionary. For example, in the first image of the stackoverflow image, i want to have all of the different visible elements [icons, link texts, buttons, paragraphs, code field, etc] .